# Accessing child class method from parent-class-typed field

Tags: java

Consider these bogus classes:

A.java

```
public class A {
    //
    // implementation...
    //
}
```

B.java

```
public class B extends A {
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    };

    //
    // B specific implementation...
    //
}
```

C.java

```
public class C extends A {
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    };

    //
    // C specific implementation...
    //
}
```

D.java

```
public class D extends A {
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    };

    //
    // D specific implementation...
    //
}
```

E.java

```
public class E extends A {
    //
    // E specific implementation...
    //
}
```

Consider the case in which you cannot change these implementations and you have a field `A a`  which will hold an object of type *B*, *C* or *D* and certainly there will be no case in which `a` hold an object of type *A* nor *E*.

Is there a cleaner way, visually speaking, of accessing method `getId()` than:

```
if (B.class.isInstance(a)) {
    return (Long) ((B) event).getId();
} else if (C.class.isInstance(a)) {
    return (Long) ((C) event).getId();
} else {
    return (Long) ((D) event).getId();
}
```

I know this is not possible, but something like this:

```
public class X extends B, C, D {
    public Long getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can't change `A`, you either have to use the instanceof chain, or reflection.

Comment: @AndyTurner I cannot change `A` nor anything related to it, i.e. `B`, `C` or any other of the bogus classes presented.

Comment: Read the bit after "if you can't change A".

Comment: @AndyTurner Yup, I was afraid reflection would be the only way of avoiding checks with `isInstance`, which would be even worse than it already is. Just wanted to know if there is any magical hidden syntax which would allow me to access a method which I know that will be there at runtime and deceive the compiler.

Comment: Can't you use an interface (seems you can't if I understand well) `interface hasId { Long getId(); }` and change B, C and D to implement it, then the code becomes `if (a instanceof HasId) { return ((HasId)a).getId() }`

Comment: (but note that you can have `class YourB extends B implement HasId`)

Comment: @RC. Despite not being able to change `B`, `C` not `D`. An interface really does solve this in a way I haven't though before: implementing classes `_B`, `_C` and `_D` all of which implements the `hasId` interface and each extends one of the original child classes. Nice way out. Make it an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use some interface here:

```
interface HasId { 
    Long getId(); 
}
```

and some custom B, C, D etc that implement it:

```
class YourB extends B implements HasId {
    // nothing
}

class YourC extends C implements HasId {
    // nothing
}

// ...
```

then the *problematic* `if` becomes

```
if (a instanceof HasId) { 
    return ((HasId) a).getId();
}
```