# PHP inheritance - Parent function with child attribute

Tags: php, inheritance

Using PHP 5.4 - Company won't upgrade because it would break existing code. Sorry about that.

Say I have a class `Resource`:

```
class Resource {
  private $resourceIdentifier;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->resourceIdentifier = "ResourceId";
  }

  public function getIdentifier() {
    return $this->resourceIdentifier;
  }
}
```

Then, that class has a child:

```
class Employee extends Resource {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->resourceIdentifier = "EmployeeId";
  }
}
```

Then I create an instance of employee and call getIdentifier()

```
$emp = new Employee();
echo $emp->getIdentifier();
```

Will the function return `$resourceIdentifier` from the parent or the child?

On top of that, what will happen if I don't define `$resourceIdentifier` in the parent but I do in the child?

```
class Resource {
  public function getIdentifier() {
    return $this->resourceIdentifier;
  }
}

class Employee extends Resource {
  private $resourceIdentifier;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->resourceIdentifier = "EmployeeId";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: Your company should invest in writing unit tests. Then you could upgrade with confidence.

Answer (score 0):

If the `$resourceIdentifier` attribute is private, then the parent class cannot access it. You need to make it protected instead:

```php
class Employee extends Resource {
  protected $resourceIdentifier;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->resourceIdentifier = "EmployeeId";
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't think about that. Assume it is protected in both situations. What is the result then?

Answer (score 0):

On top of that, what will happen if I don't define $resourceIdentifier in the parent but I do in the child?

> Answer:
>
> If you define it has parent and call it in child you are following the
>   concept of inheritance, hence you can use the same $resourceIdentifier
>   for many childs.

Will the function return $resourceIdentifier from the parent or the child?

> Answer:
>   [Accessing child class method from parent-class-typed field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514787/accessing-child-class-method-from-parent-class-typed-field)

Trying looking at this